# Adobe Animate CC - Export WebGL with transparent background

Tags: webgl, animate-cc

I've been trying to find a way of exporting a WebGL project with a transparent background in Adobe Animate CC. I've tried setting the CSS background-color to transparent, but that didn't work, and it doesn't appear that there are any preferences in the IDE that suggest you can have a transparent background. I want to overlay the animation on top of existing elements.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make Animate CC's WebGL output have transparent background.
It's not supported currently and there doesn't seem to be any workaround either.

Answer (score 0):

step 1. Make a change in your `libs/flwebgl-0.2.min.js`:
change: `alpha:!1` to `alpha:1`

step 2. In your json file change `stageColor` value:
`"stageColor":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"`